# Как выполнить вложенный запрос

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы. Первая Calendar содержит 3 столбца: id помещения, время и имя пользователя. Вторая Rooms содержит 2 столбца: id помещения и название помещения.
Требуется по имени пользователя вывести все строчки из таблицы Calendar, но чтобы вместо id помещения, выводилось соответствующее название из таблицы Rooms

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам подзапрос? Можно использовать обычный join.

```
Select "Название помещения", "Время", "Имя пользователя"
from Calendar c  join Rooms r on c."id Помещения"=r."id Помещения"
where "Имя пользователя"='Блаблабла'
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Просто и понятно!

Comment: если ответ подошел - отметьте его галочкой